# What is an unboxed value in GHC Haskell and when should we use them?

Tags: haskell, ghc

GHC Haskell exposes the `prim` package, which contains definitions of unboxed values, such as `Int#`, `Char#`, etc.

- How do they differ from the default `Int`, `Char`, etc., types in regular Haskell? An assumption would be that they're faster, but why?
- When should one reach down to use these instead of the boxed regular alternatives?
- How does using boxed vs unboxed value affect the program?

Comment: I've written [an article](http://alpmestan.com/posts/2013-10-02-oh-my-laziness.html) about this, you may want to give it a shot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In simple terms, a value of type `Int` may be an unevaluated expression. The actual value isn't calculated until you "look at" the value.

A value of type `Int#` is an evaluated result. Always.

As a result of this, a `Int` a data structure that lives on the heap. An `Int#` is... just a 32-bit integer. It can live in a CPU register. You can operate on it with a single machine instruction. It has almost no overhead.

By contrast, when you write, say, `x + 1`, you're not actually *computing* x + 1, you're creating a data structure on the heap that says "when you want to compute this, do x + 1".

Put simply, `Int#` is faster, because it can't be lazy.

When should you use it? Almost never. That's the compiler's job. The idea being that you write nice high-level Haskell code involving `Int`, and *the compiler* figures out where it can replace `Int` with `Int#`. (We hope!) If it doesn't, it's almost always easier to throw in a few strictness annotations rather than play with `Int#` directly. (It's also non-portable; only GHC uses `Int#` - although currently there aren't really any other widely used Haskell compilers.)

Comment: A couple of days ago I compared the performance of `Int`s (with strict evaluation) and `Int#`. When compiled with `-O2`, there's literally *no difference* in performance. GHC does the job well.

Comment: And you can take a look at the generated core to see where GHC is or isn't unboxing types for you